# How to make an dynamic SQL SELECT query by passing in a comma separated list of values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a column in my SQL database (using mySQL) 'lastname', which has any number of employee's last names in it. I want to write a query that handles a search for last names using a comma delimited list.

So the user will type:

```
Garcia, Smith, Jones
```

And that gets stored in a String, `lastNameQuery`, which then gets passed into my backend API function that calls the SQL command. I want to return all employees in the DB that have those last names.

Is there any kind of SQL SELECT command I can use that search using a list like that? For my other functions (which only handle a single search term) I'm using this:

```
"SELECT * FROM employees WHERE salary LIKE '%${salary}%'"
```

Which works great. Is there some way I can modify it to handle a list?  I can always break up the single String (`"Garcia, Smith, Jones"`) into an array if necessary so that's not a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: You can convert your comma-separated list into a temporary table structure or array(however MySql handles these things) and then use that in a join clause: `select * from Employee join temp on Employee.LastName = temp.LastName)`. You can probably find many hits on "converting CSV to table" for your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either do:

```
(lastname like '%Garcia%' or lastname like '%Smith%' or lastname like '%jones%')
```

or create a fulltext index on lastname (`alter table employess add fulltext (lastname)`) which would let you do

```
match (lastname) against ('Garcia, Smith, Jones')
```

but won't do things like find Garcia if you search for just "Garc".

Comment: For that fulltext solution, with your SQL command (`alter table add fulltext (lastname)`) is `lastname` referencing just the SQL column name I already have? Or did you mean that to be the lastNameQuery string? The first solution wouldn't work unfortunately as it can't be hardcoded, I have to dynamically create the string depending on the search. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: the sql column name you already have

Comment: that worked! Thank you. For anyone else reading looking for the solution, the full SQL statement/solution looks like this:  `ALTER TABLE employees ADD FULLTEXT index_name(lastname);`   And the SQL called in code looks like `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE MATCH(lastname) against(lastNameQuery);` (where `lastNameQuery` is that comma delimited list).

Comment: oh, sorry, didn't mean to leave the table name out of the alter table.  index name is optional, but a good thing to specify since it will make one up for you if you don't say.